# Change values in data frame in one column where some other column is equal to some text.

Tags: r

Given the following dataframe. How can I change all hab type to "ungrazed" where Study area is equal to "B". It seems I would need to use an apply function, but I can't seem to unravel the correct construction. Thanks in advance.

```
hab type     Study area
grazed          A
grazed          A
grazed          B
grazed          B
grazed          C
grazed          C
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
df$hab.type[df$Study.area=='B'] <- 'Ungrazed'
df
#  hab.type Study.area
#1   grazed          A
#2   grazed          A
#3 Ungrazed          B
#4 Ungrazed          B
#5   grazed          C
#6   grazed          C
```

Or

```
transform(df, hab.type=replace(hab.type, Study.area=='B', 'Ungrazed'))
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(hab.type = c("grazed", "grazed", "grazed", "grazed", 
"grazed", "grazed"), Study.area = c("A", "A", "B", "B", "C", 
"C")), .Names = c("hab.type", "Study.area"), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```